# JS : Detect within an iframe from other domain if it is visible or not

Tags: javascript, iframe, visibility

I have an issue with knowing whether my iframe placed inside a HTML doc is visible (above the fold) or not.

My webpage : https://oneserver.com/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://otherserver.com/index.html></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The other webpage (not the that should do something when the parent iframe is visible :

```
<html>
<head></head
<body>
<script>
if(document.isVisible()){document.style.background="red"}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried with Page Visibility API and a jquery trick, but I found no solution so far. Can you please help me on that matter ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you mean to use `<iframe src="https://otherserver.com/index.html></iframe>`?

Comment: Yes sorry @monly00 , i corrected it !

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine if it is visible, it has to be able to detect the size of the parent window and how far that window has scrolled.

Standard cross-origin security makes this impossible to achieve from inside the frame.

The best you can do is to have the code in the parent page detect when the frame enters or leaves the view, and then use [the postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to tell the page in the frame about that event.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin ! But unfortunately I don't have access to the webpage served on the onedomain.com.

Comment: @Nico — Then you certainly can't spy on what your visitors are doing on that other site.